# ASP.NET HttpHandlers and scriptProcessor path on web.config

Tags: .net, asp.net, msbuild, web-config, ihttphandler

I'm defining http handlers on my web.config:

```
<add name="nsi" path="i.nsi" verb="GET" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0" />
```

The scriptProcessor points to the *Framework64* folder as the server running this is 64bit.
However, our development machines are 32bit. Which means the handler won't run unless I checkout the web.config and change *Framework64* to *Framework*.

Is there a way to write this so that it runs on any machine? both 32bit and 64bit?
An environment variable or an MSBuild script that can help?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this ?

```
scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll"
```